# Too much time to upload a file to ganache-cli blockchain

Tags: solidity, ganache, ganache-cli

I am trying to upload a `1.6 Mb` file to a state variable of type `bytes` in a smart contract I deployed in ganache blockchain, so I started it using this command to avoid the `out of gas` error in python web3

```
ganache --miner.blockGasLimit 999999999999 --miner.callGasLimit 999999999999
```

The problem is that when I ran the smart contract function that updates the state variable with the file bytes, it took about 3 minutes to be done for the first time, but when I tried again, it takes so long, and when I stop ganache, an `connection error` immediatly appears. I kept retrying but the same thing happens, it just does not display anything.

this is my smart contract code

```
contract NodeContract {

    bytes latestModelWeights;

    function setWeights(bytes memory weights) public {
        latestModelWeights = weights;
    } 

    function getWeights() public returns (bytes memory) {
        return latestModelWeights;
    }

}
```

and this is the python code used to update and read from the blockchain

```
from web3 import Web3
import time

t1 = time.time()

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545",  request_kwargs={'timeout': 600}))

address = "0x254dffcd3277C0b1660F6d42EFbB754edaBAbC2B"

abi = '[{"inputs":[],"name":"getWeights","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"","type":"bytes"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes","name":"weights","type":"bytes"}],"name":"setWeights","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]'

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)

compressed_file_bytes = bytes(open("ok.gz", "rb").read())

tx_hash = contract.functions.setWeights(compressed_file_bytes).transact({"from": "0x90F8bf6A479f320ead074411a4B0e7944Ea8c9C1"})

w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

t2 = time.time()

print("finished transaction 1")

bytes = contract.functions.getWeights().call()

with open("ok2.gz", "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytes)

t3 = time.time()

print("time for saving: ", int((t2 - t1) / 60))
print("time for reading: ", int((t3 - t2) / 60))
```

I know I should not upload a file to the blockchain, but I need it for my project, is the problem in my code or in the `ganache` gas settings?